# Issue importing Akka packages

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have the following `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "akkaHttp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"


resolvers ++= Seq("Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  Resolver.bintrayRepo("hseeberger", "maven"))


libraryDependencies ++= {
  val AkkaVersion       = "2.3.9"
  val AkkaHttpVersion   = "2.0.1"
  val Json4sVersion     = "3.2.11"
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j"      % AkkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-experimental" % AkkaHttpVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback"    %  "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
    "org.json4s"        %% "json4s-native"   % Json4sVersion,
    "org.json4s"        %% "json4s-ext"      % Json4sVersion,
    "de.heikoseeberger" %% "akka-http-json4s" % "1.4.2"
  )
}
```

In it, these dependencies are not met.

```
Error:Unresolved dependencies:
com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.12;2.3.9: not found
com.typesafe.akka#akka-http-experimental_2.12;2.0.1: not found
org.json4s#json4s-native_2.12;3.2.11: not found
org.json4s#json4s-ext_2.12;3.2.11: not found
de.heikoseeberger#akka-http-json4s_2.12;1.4.2: not found
```

So what should I add to it such that the imports work?

Comment: AFAIK , akka 2.3.9 hasn't been built and published in maven against 2.12 . Its available for scala 2.11.x . Try using scala version as 2.11.8 .

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `_2.12` appended to the artifacts? Based on your `scalaVersion`, SBT tried to download the dependencies built against Scala 2.12.x, but couldn't find any. Try using Scala version 2.11.8.

Different versions of Scala can be binary incompatible, so libraries are cross built against those different versions and published to the repositories. Looks like it hasn't yet happened for those libraries above.

Note that Scala 2.12 is indeed [not binary compatible](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0) with Scala 2.11.